# Calculating time intervals in Python, a more smarter way

Tags: python, datetime, string-concatenation, timedelta, strptime

was trying to calculate and a timedelta element with a str concatente, finally got it but feel there should be a smarter way to do this, any idea pls. here are my lines of code:

```
import datetime
import time
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
print("The time now is " + currentTime.strftime('%I:%M %p'))
realTime = currentTime.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
```

## realTime was necessary to convert the datetime currentTime to a str to feed to strptime

```
print(realTime)
meetTime = input("Please input the meeting time in 12hrs timing")
# timeToMeet = datetime.datetime.strptime('11:50PM', '%I:%M%p').time()
timeToMeet = datetime.datetime.strptime(meetTime, '%I:%M%p')
```

## tried both static and input time and they both worked

```
print(timeToMeet.strftime('%H:%M %p'))
timeNow = datetime.datetime.strptime(realTime, '%I:%M:%S %p')
print("The time now is " + timeNow.strftime('%I:%M%p'))
tdelta = timeToMeet - timeNow
print("Please, your meeting starts in " + str(tdelta))
print(tdelta)
```

Comment: You calculate a timedelta from datetime objects - that's perfectly fine. how to make this "smarter" depends on what you want to achieve...

Comment: More like have a fewer lines of code for thesame effect

Comment: That doesn't clarify *what* you want to write in less lines of code ;-) Also, keep in mind that *less lines* aren't always *more readable* - you have to find a balance here if you want to understand what you did when you come back to your code in the future.